# ng-repeat through an Array of Objects

Tags: angularjs, stamplay

I'm creating a little shoutbox with angular JS and StamPlay. Therefore I've created some 'Test Shouts' than can be accesed via an [URL](https://shoutbox.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/shouts)

In my Angular app I've created a Service to fetch the data:

```js
app.factory('shouts', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return $http.get('https://shoutbox.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/shouts').success(function (data) {
        return data.data;
    });

}]);
```

Inside my MainController I attach the data to the $scope.

```js
app.controller('HomeController', [
    '$scope',
    'shouts',

    function ($scope, shouts) {
        $scope.shouts = shouts;
    }

]);
```

But when I'm tyring to ng-repeat through the data[], i can't access the objects inside. I don't understand whats the problem.

```html
<div ng-repeat="shout in shouts">
  {{shout.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: Any error thrown in the console window? Also - you should be using track by - for performance e.g. ng-repeat="shout in shouts track by $index"

Comment: unfortunately there are no errors in console. You can view the app running here: https://shoutbox.stamplayapp.com/#/

Comment: and the HTML and component/directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouts is a $promise even you do "return data.data". So you need to assign $scope.shouts when the promise resolved.

```
app.factory('shouts', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return $http.get('https://shoutbox.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/shouts');

}]);

app.controller('HomeController', [
    '$scope',
    'shouts',

    function ($scope, shouts) {
       shouts.then(function(data) { $scope.shouts = data.data});
    }

]);
```

Another options is to resolve shouts in you route config and inject it into the controller

```
$routeProvider
.when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "home.html",
    controller: "HomeController",
    resolve: {
        shout_data: shouts
    }


app.controller('HomeController', [
    '$scope',
    'shout_data',

    function ($scope, shout_data) {
       $scope.shouts = shout_data;
    }

]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: shouts().then(function(data) { $scope.shouts = data.data});

Comment: <div ng-repeat="shout in shouts.data">{{shout.title}}</div>

That solved my problem!
Seems like the way Stamplay is returning the Data is a bit awkward

Comment: Do i do the adding of a new shout:{} to my backend inside the service or inside the MainController? I mean the http post request.

Comment: For the sake of Single responsibility principle, do it in service.  if your back-end is REST api, consider using $resource

Comment: Using the $resource, I have again a problem with the format how stamplay api returns the data. $resource.query() seems to be expecting an Array of Objects but the API returns:


    {
    "data": [],
    "pagination": {}
    }

And i need to geht the data[] with Objects inside

Comment: you still do something like $scope.shouts = queryResult.data in your query's callback

Comment: Yes but I get an error from $resource:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=https:%2F%2Fshoutbox.stamplayapp.com%2Fapi%2Fcobject%2Fv1%2Fshouts

Comment: instead of  query, call $resouce.get

Comment: Hi @juleee , Isaiah here with Stamplay. Can I ask how the data is being returned from Stamplay?

Also feel free to use the intercom button inside the Stamplay editor on the bottom right corner for more direct support.

Let me know, I'm happy to take a look at how Stamplay is responding to your query :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to attach your controller to the HTML?

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div ng-repeat="shout in shouts">
      {{shout.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

More information about ngController: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: No, i attached the Controller to my View via the $routeProvider